# is it haram for parents to push you to do something you don't like

Tags: halal-haram

my parents always push me to do something I don't like so I just wanted to know if it is haram for parents to push you to do something you don't like

Comment: can anyone reply to my question

Answer (score 1):

> “And We have enjoined on man (to be dutiful and good) to his parents.  His mother bore him in weakness and hardship upon weakness and hardship, and his weaning is in two years give thanks to Me and to your parents, unto Me is the final destination.” 
>  Quran 31:14

> “If anyone possesses these three characteristics God will give him an
> easy death and bring him into His Paradise: gentleness towards the
> weak, affection towards parents, and kindness to slaves.” 
>  Tirmidhi

> "And your Lord has decreed that you not worship except Him, and to
> parents, good treatment. Whether one or both of them reach old age
> [while] with you, say not to them [so much as], "uff," and do not
> repel them but speak to them a noble word." 
>  Quran 17:23

You must obey your parents, even if you don't want to. You must be respectful towards them. The only time you shouldn't listen to them would be if they're making you do something that goes against Islam.
So again, the only way for it to be haram to listen to them would be if they force you to go against Islam.

Comment: ok I understand